# Saving plot as svg() crashes R on OSX 10.9.1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to save a plot in R as an SVG file.

when I specify `svg(filename="plot.svg")` and hit enter, R crashes every single time. It crashes because X11 is no longer supported in OSX and XQuartz is used instead. Is there an alternative way I can save plots in SVG?

Comment: `Cairo` package for mac, you can get x11 from the xquartz people

Comment: Maybe get help from the r-sig-mac mailing list?